# Slack WebClient - How to close modal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api

I'm trying to handle view_submission, it always show error after submit (although in back-end all processes have been done successful).

**We had some trouble connecting. Try again?**

Would anyone know how to close the modal in this case?

```
slack_client.views_push(trigger_id=trigger_id, view=updated_view)
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to respond to slack  with 200 OK with an empty body. This will complete the the closure for the current view.

> If your app responds to a view_submission event with a basic acknowledgment response — an HTTP 200 response — this will immediately close the submitted view, and remove it from the view stack.

If you want to close all the views in the modal then what you need to set the `response_action` to clear. For more information on this check out slacks guide to using modals [here](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#closing_views)